# How to handle CORS with Socket.io V3

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to set up socket.io for the first time, I keep getting `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`.

I read the documentation for handling CORS but I still keep getting the same error.

```
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NU1vFwA. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import { createServer } from 'http'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import cors from 'cors'
import processes from './routes/process.js'

const app = express()
const httpServer = createServer(app)

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST']
  }
})


app.use(cors())

app.use('/apiLink/process', processes)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New client connected')
  socket.emit('FromAPI', 'Hello socket.io')
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected')
  })
})


httpServer.listen(4000, () => console.log(`Socket.io test running on port 4000`))
```

client.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

const Main = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:4000')
    socket.on('FromAPI', (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })

    return () => socket.disconnect()
  }, [])

  return <h1>Test</h1>
}

export default Main
```

I am running the version 3.1.1 and according to their site, I need to explicitly enable CORS which I have but still the browser responds with CORS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird, contrary to the documentation I got it working by changing this on the server

```
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: true,
  origins: ['http://locahost:4000']
})
```